# Mongoose schema method and .pre('save') not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I can't understand why the schema.method.log and schema.pre('save') doesn't work.

I appreciate any help!

```js
// plugin.js

const LogSchema = require('../models/log')

const plugin = function (schema) {

    schema.post('init', doc => {
       console.log(doc)
    })

    schema.pre('save', function(next) {
      console.log('save') // <---------- this method is not executed!
      next()
    })

    schema.methods.log = function(data) {
        return LogSchema.create(data)
    }
}

module.exports = plugin
```

```js
// products.js

const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Products = mongoose.model('products')

router.post('/', async (req, res) => { // <--- POST method

  const product = new Products({
    name: req.body.name,
  })
  
  console.log(typeof product.log) // <---------- `UNDEFINED !`
  
  await product.save() // <--- product save correctly

  res.json({
    status: 'Product Saved'
  })
})
```

```js
// index.js
[...]

mongoose.plugin(require('./server/middlewares/plugin.js')) // <----- Works well

[...]
```

I'm fairly new to the MongoDB, and after scouring the code for a few hours I can't see why things are going wrong.

Comment: schema.pre('save'  must be used before const Products = mongoose.model('products');  Why don't you write a product.js which contains your productSchema and product model? What is that plugin stuff?

Comment: schema.method.log I use it as a global method for all my routes, not just products.  I have many routes

Comment: As I said schema.pre('save'.. must be used before const Products = mongoose.model('products');  arrange your code to do like that.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you have a simple example of what it would be like?